# Inequality regarding measure of function and integral of function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f$ be a measurable
>   function and $t > 0, t\in \mathbb{R}.$.
>
> Denote: $$C_f(t) = \mu \{x \in \Omega : |f(x)| \geq t \}.$$

In the first part of this question (from a past paper), I showed that
$$C_{f+g}(t) \leq C_f(t/2) + C_g(t/2).$$
I'm not sure if this relates to the next part or not.

> (b) For any integers $n,m \geq 1$ prove that
>   $$C_f(t) \leq \frac{1}{t^n + t^m} \int (|f|^n + |f|^m)d\mu.$$

In all honesty, I'm not even sure where to start with this. It's only four marks which suggests I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int(|f|^n+|f|^m)\ \mathsf d\mu &\geqslant \int_{\{|f|\geqslant t\}}(|f|^n+|f|^m)\ \mathsf d\mu\\ 
&\geqslant \int_{\{|f|\geqslant t\}} (t^n + t^m)\ \mathsf d\mu\\
&=C_f(t)(t^n+t^m).
\end{align}

Comment: Cheers. Any way you could share your thought process here? I stared at this for good amount of time without spotting it.

Comment: $x\mapsto x^n$ is increasing so if $|f(x)|\geqslant t$ then $|f(x)|^n\geqslant t$. There's not a whole lot to explain really.